# After installing a package, is_installed returns still False, in python apt

Tags: apt, python

by using python apt, i can install packages. Before and after installing the package, i updated the cache. However, before and after installing the package, is_installed returns the same, in other words, it gives wrong result.

After installing the package, i need to check whether the package is installed or not. Here is my code :

```
import apt.cache

def cache_update():
    cache = apt.cache.Cache()    
    cache.update()
    pkg = cache["p7zip-full"]
    print pkg.is_installed  # prints false

    if pkg.is_installed:
       print "it is already installed. Invalid request! "
       pkg.mark_delete()
    else:
       print "it is not installed.Now you are installing..."
       pkg.mark_install()

    cache.commit()


    print "DONE."
    cache.update()  
    print pkg.is_installed # prints false.



if __name__ == '__main__':
    cache_update()
```

Comment: why using pkg.mark_delete() when package is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, python doesn't carry over the variable after the `cache.commit()`.  If you define it again afterwards, it returns the right `pkg.is_installed` answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import apt.cache
pack1 = 'p7zip-full'

def cache_update():
    cache = apt.cache.Cache()    
    cache.update()
    pkg = cache[pack1]
    print pkg.is_installed  # prints false

    if pkg.is_installed:
       print "it is already installed. Invalid request! "
       pkg.mark_delete()
    else:
       print "it is not installed.Now you are installing..."
       pkg.mark_install()

    cache.commit()

    print "DONE."
    cache = apt.cache.Cache()
    pkg = cache[pack1]
    print pkg.is_installed # prints true.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cache_update()
```

Comment: Is there a way to track the progress of the install ? After executing cache.commit, I don't know how to track the progress if there's multiple installs or removes. Might you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can re-init with open() like so:

```
cache.commit()
cache.open()
print cache[pack1].is_installed
```